# How do I check if a site already exists from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I have a script that exports a site and restores it in another web application.  I want to check if the target site already exists.  Is there an easy way to tell if www.example.org/sites/asite/ is free, without throwing an error in Powershell?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Using Powershell's [ErrorAction](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd315352.aspx) you can suppress the error if a web does not exist.

```
$exists = (Get-SPWeb $url -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -ne $null
```

Answer (score 8):

SharePoint 2010:

```
Get-SPWeb -Identity $url | Select-Object -Property Exists -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
```

SharePoint 2007:

```
[void][reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$siteCollection = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite($url)
$site = $siteCollection.OpenWeb()
Write-Host $site.Exists
...
$site.Dispose()
$siteCollection.Dispose()
```

Comment: +1, good answer :)

Comment: This throws an error still:

Get-SPWeb -Identity 'http://example.org' | Select-Object -Property Exists 

The 2007 version doesn't throw errors but returns true for sites that don't exist.

Comment: Do you prefix the url with protocol moniker such as http://? It is obligatory I believe.

Comment: Get-SPWeb : Cannot find an SPSite object that contains the following Id or Url: example.org.  -- this is what you get in case that web never existed

Comment: You can either swallow the error by using -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue or handle it using trap, try/catch or 2>&1. Read on PowerShell error handling elsewhere.