# New-PnPSite - Check if site is allready created?

Tags: sharepoint-online, site, pnp-powershell, pnp

```
# CREATE COMMUNICATION SITE
New-PnPSite `
  -Type CommunicationSite `
  -Title $team `
  -Url ("https://hiddenforsecurity.sharepoint.com/sites/" + $team) `
  -SiteDesign 'Blank'
```

I need to wrap this in a if statement that will check if the site is already created, can anybody point me in the right direction?

TY :)

Comment: have you checked [this](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/12752/how-do-i-check-if-a-site-already-exists-from-powershell)? This is using PowerShell.

Comment: Also check [this](https://malcolm1215.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/sharepoint-online-site-operation-with-pnp-powershell/). This is using PnP Powershell and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Thats what I was looking for! Thank you :D

Comment: Great, glad it worked for you. Please [upvote ( ^ )](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173399/how-to-upvote-on-stack-overflow) and [accept it as an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like below:

```
$site = Get-SPOWeb -Identity "Site" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if ($subsite -eq $null) {
  Write-Host "Site does not exist, create..." -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
else {
  Write-Host "Subsite already exist" -ForegroundColor Green
}
```

**Reference**:

[SharePoint Online: Site Operation with PnP Powershell](https://malcolm1215.wordpress.com/2017/01/05/sharepoint-online-site-operation-with-pnp-powershell/).

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `Get-PnPTenantSite` command to check if a site collection exists or not as below:

```
$site = ""
Try
{
    Write-Host "Checking, if site already exists..."

    $site = Get-PnPTenantSite -Url "<your-site-url>" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
}
Catch
{    
}

if ($site -ne $null)
{
    Write-Host "Site already exists, use existing..."
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Site doesn't exist, creating new..."
}
```

Comment: Thx!  I was trying to use Get-PNPSite and Get-PNPWeb with no luck.